# Required torque of climbing tracked vehicle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, electric-vehicles

Currently I'm designing a tracked vehicle for a school project. It has to carry a weight and be able to overcome some obstacles which are about 3/4th the height of the tank. What I'm stuck at, is calculating the required torque for the motors. 
[image: Basic layout with variables. The upper right wheel is going to be powered.]

This is the basic layout of the tank with some variables. The wheel in the upper right is going to be powered.
Given that there will be enough traction between the tracks and the obstacle, how can I accurately calculate the required torque for the motor of this tracked vehicle to climb the obstacles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max torque at the time of the climbing is

Let's call the power wheel radius .r.

T=mg*sin(theta)*r

After the track passes the hump of non powered wheel the tank will flip back, because it's CG falls back outside of the track footprint.